# Making Article Titel not Clickable

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I was wondering how I can make the Article Titel not clickable, since it does not serve any purpose. ( Where the word " Welcome " ist in the picture

[Picture : Joomla Titel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggWap.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the menu item and set in Option - Hypertextual titles: No

Comment: It didn't work at first, only when i now put it on global options so its for every joomla article.

Comment: Strange, the normal joomla operation is like this. Are you sure you have entered the right menu item?